# How to avoid clicking "accept" twice in Metamask (on approve and transferFrom) using EthersJS?

Tags: solidity, metamask, ethers.js

To transfer a token from a wallet to my contract I need to do both:

1. `token.connect(signer).approve(contract.address, amount)` (frontend)
2. `IERC20(token).transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), amount)` (backend)

Both prompt Metamask to ask the user to "accept".

From a user experience perspective, it's annoying to have to click "accept" twice.

But if I skip the first step, there is an error.

```
ERC20: insufficient allowance
```

Am I missing something that would allow only asking the user to click "accept" once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is annoying, but every major app working with ERC-20 has the exact same UI. Why?

Because of fundamental limitations in ERC-20 design, **contracts must *pull* the ERC-20**, otherwise they cannot know who sent the ERC-20, and therefore cannot credit you with them.

However, they need to be `approve`d before they can be allowed to pull.

The options to get around this are:

1. Use ERC-777 and utilize hooks
2. Approve an infinite amount once at the start
3. Use ETH instead of ERC-20, as ETH can trigger the fallback/receive function (which ERC-20 cannot)

It's probably the single biggest point of friction for the ERC-20 token spec. The next biggest is sending tokens directly (pushing tokens to a contract, instead of letting them pull tokens). If you do that, you've basically burned the tokens.

---

So, assuming we're working with USDC, to pick a random ERC-20:

what you have to do:

1. *USER* tells USDC contract that *your contract* is approved to withdraw **x** tokens.
2. *USER* tells *your contract* to go withdraw the USDC from *USER* account.
3. All good, because *your contract* has permission.

And what you're trying to do:

1. *USER* tells *your contract* to go withdraw the USDC from *USER* account.
2. USDC contract rejects, because *your contract* doesn't have permission to touch *USER* funds.

If USDC validated by checking `tx.origin` instead of `msg.sender`, this would work! [It would also be a huge security flaw](https://solidity-by-example.org/hacks/phishing-with-tx-origin/), and many tokens have been lost by people trying to take that shortcut.